# How to put UIImageView on the background of the layout

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, layout, uiimageview

Greetz,

So this is rather a simple question (maybe not a simple answer). I want the IB option called 'send to back' (On IB, go to Layout -> Send to back) to be done programmatically.

Is it possible? If not, any suggestions to simulate the same thing?

This is for an UIImageView as the title states.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `sendSubviewToBack:`

```
[yourSubView.superview sendSubviewToBack:yourSubView];
```

Comment: Okay this is what I need but is there a sendSubViewToFront equivalent? It seems there isn't one. This one just sends the view too far back, behind the view itself so it dissappears from view...

Comment: @Joze : - (void)bringSubviewToFront:(UIView *)view Plz read the apple Documentation for UIView            http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html

Answer (score 1):

```
[self insertSubview:view atIndex:index];
```

Just experiment with the index you need.