# Bring image to background

Tags: xcode

Does anyone know how I can bring this (see code) image to the background? It's no 'hanging' over an other image which I placed in the Interface Builder

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 104)];
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"helloworld.png"]];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: [imageView bringSubviewToFront:yourImage];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe
`[yourSubView.superview sendSubviewToBack:yourSubView];`
Look at this question: [How to put UIImageView on the background of the layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565505/how-to-put-uiimageview-on-the-background-of-the-layout)